# What happens if anyone GET url created by angular

Tags: html, angularjs, web, get

At the [AngularJS](http://www.angularjs.org) website, and the *API Reference* section, when you click on links, the URL changes in the location bar, I know this is done by `$routeProvider.when()` method so I call it a **Fake URL** because this URL only refers to the sub page not whole page with layout, because, when you click on a link, just the sub page is loaded into `ng-view` not the whole page including header, footer etc. (layout at all).

They might have something like this:

```
 $routeProvider
 .when('/$routeProvider', {
     templateUrl: '/$routeProvider',
     controller: 'routeProviderCtrl',
 })
```

Certainly the `html` file returned by `/$routeProvider` does not contain anything about page layout, because it doesn't need to. I Mean if you enter `http://www.example.com/$routeProvider` in the location bar we'll get a sub-page template, which will eventually load into `ng-view`.

But for example this URL https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider, if we enter this URL in the location bar and press enter (send a GET) the whole the page with all layout specific parts will be loaded.

My question is **HOW?**

What happens when we enter a URL which is created by AngularJS? How can I handle that and decide to send whole page or just template?

Comment: Read about HTML5 mode and History API

Comment: the people that wrote UI-Router also wrote a really good article on this topic.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: thank u @Claies it was really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: the *web server* disregards the details of the URL.

Pretty much whatever URL you request from `docs.angularjs.org`, it will always return the exact same bootstrap page containing the Angular script and other resources required for the page. The Angular script itself will then inspect the URL and load the requested template/page into the view.

Playing around on the command line:

```
$ curl https://docs.angularjs.org/ > a.html
$ curl https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute > b.html
$ diff a.html b.html 
$
```

`diff` not outputting anything means both files are identical.

Comment: A GREAT THANK!! I was thinking of that but I was not sure. so if I return just one file for all request to `http://www.example.com`, then how can I access my real routes? for example suppose my templates are located in `http://www.example.com/templates`

Comment: Well, you'd make an appropriate exception for `/templates` on your server, or serve from a subdomain or some such.